# Slicing a spreadsheet in Python terminal

Tags: python, slice

So I'm making a program that asks a server a data and it send back. The problem is when I ask for some data it answer:

[image: Terminal]

And I need just the value from the column "Close" . I can't figure out how to do it.

Code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import time


stock = yf.Ticker("MSFT")

data = stock.history(period="1")
oferta= stock.info["bid"]

print(data)
```

Comment: Please provide relevant code.

Comment: import yfinance as yf
import time


stock = yf.Ticker("MSFT")

data = stock.history(period="1")
oferta= stock.info["bid"]

print(data)

Answer (score 0):

yfinance uses the pandas library to return data. You are receiving a pandas' DataFrame object in `data`, so to select only the "Close" column you can do this:

```
print(data["Close"].iloc[0])
```

Comment: This is the first thing I tried. But this is what is printed: `Date
2020-04-07    163.49
Name: Close, dtype: float64` and I need just the value 163.49

Comment: Do you always want the first cell in the column?

Comment: Yes. The first is enough